# Moving UITabBarItem Image down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Normally on each tab of a `UITabBar` you have a small image and a title naming the tab. The image is positioned/centred towards the top of the tab to accommodate the title underneath. My question is: *if you want to have a tabBar with just an image and no title is there a way to move the image down so it centers better within the tab?*

I am using (see below) currently:

```
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:tabSelected withFinishedUnselectedImage:tabUnselected];
```

but would prefer to use to larger image with no title, at the moment if I make the image bigger than about 70pixels@2x it starts edging off the top of the `UITabBar` whilst leaving a lot of unused space at the bottom.

Answer (score 196):

Try adjusting `tabBarItem`'s `imageInsets` (for moving the icon image) and setting the controllers title to nil (so no title is displayed). Put something like this to `-init` or `-viewDidLoad` method in view controller:

**Objective-C**

```
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
self.title = nil;
```

**Swift**

```
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
self.title = nil
```

`UITabBarItem` is a subclass of `UIBarItem` which has `UIEdgeInsets imageInsets` property. Play a little with the insets until it looks good (depending on your tabbar icon images)

**iPad specific adjustments**

Tab Bar items on iPad are distributed horizontally (icon and label next to each other).

To adjust space between icon and label, adjust horizontal `imageInsets` instead of vertical ones.

Comment: This solved my problem. I made a subclass of UITabBarController and iterated self.tabBar.items.

Comment: @Lukas: but this shrinks images.

Comment: @Sourabh Doesn't shrink them for me

Comment: @Javy I was doing it wrong earlier..its working fine now. appologies i didn't update the comment.

Comment: The actual inset value is 5.5f if you need it to be pixel perfect.

Comment: where should this method be placed at? I mean I need to customise 3 tabbaritems but I can only customise one item in one viewDidLoad of the entry of tabs right?

Comment: this works fine, is there a way to also move the badge? I currently have a floating badge

Comment: @rr1g0 Moving the badge to custom position is not possible. If you need custom position of a badge or custom badge appearance, you must implement it yourself

Comment: I used this too. Worked fine for iOS 9, 10 and 11 (iPhone 8). But with iPhone X it has no effect. Noting changed. Any Idea about that?

Comment: @Sourabh you have to offset the bottom with a negative value to not shrink the image.

Comment: any idea how can we achieve the same using SwiftUI? I use a tabView and have multiple TabItems inside

Answer (score 156):

You can do it via storyboard too. Select your tabbaritem, go to size inspector and assign the appropriate insets.

[image]

**Demonstrated on Xcode, Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)*

Comment: nice and clean!

Comment: Best of all the answers...Thank you so much @Neil Galiaskarov

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 55):

Make a subclass of `UITabBarController`, and in its `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIViewController *vc, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        vc.tabBarItem.title = nil;
        vc.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    }];
}
```

Swift 3:

```
for vc in self.viewControllers! {
    vc.tabBarItem.title = nil
    vc.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0)
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. just that for swift the method enumerateObjectsUsingBlock is not available any more

Comment: don't subclass, instead put this in to your AppDelegate

Comment: putting this snippet in `AppDelegate` also works, but it's not obviously better than subclassing it. You can have your own preference though :)

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me

**Swift 4**

```
let array = tabBarController?.customizableViewControllers
for controller in array! {
    controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Xamarin, this works:

```
screen.TabBarItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(5, 0, -5, 0);
screen.TabBarItem.Title = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.0**

You can set image lnsets, set top,left,bottom and right according desing.

```
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 11 you need to override **TraitCollection** method apart from setting ImageInsets. 
Please add the method in your subclassed UITabBarController class

```
public override UITraitCollection TraitCollection {
 get {
  return UITraitCollection.FromHorizontalSizeClass(horizontalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact);
 }
}
```

Comment: Good tip that helped me solve an issue related to the image position for tab bar item on iPad and iOS 11. But it's too harsh to override the trait collection at the view controller level, it's better to subclass the UITabBar class and override the traitCollection property there. Also returning a trait collection with only the horizontal class, will drop other trait collection properties. `return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [ super.traitCollection, UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)])` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2**, `UIEdgeInsetsMake` is depricated, instead we should use `UIEdgeInsets`,

```
let array = tabBarController?.customizableViewControllers
    for controller in array! {
        controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

These didn't work for me, the only solution that worked was setting the *alignmentRectInsets* when adding the image. Here's what mine looked like:

```
let newsView = NewsViewController()
let newsIcon = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(systemName: "newspaper")?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.5, left: 0, bottom: -8.5, right: 0)), tag: 0)
newsView.tabBarItem = newsIcon
let viewControllers = [newsNavController]
self.viewControllers = viewControllers
```

Answer (score 1):

### In 2021, Objective-C

I try all the approaches, no one is worked. Eventually I found that is because of using SF symbol as tabbaritem image. If I replace it with custom image, things worked.

```
    NSArray *tabItems = [self.tabBar items];
    // set tabItem icon, remove blue image with render mode set.
    UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIcon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    
    // set title offset
    [tabItems[0] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 20)];
    [tabItems[1] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-20, 20)];
    [tabItems[2] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(20, 20)];
    [tabItems[3] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 20)];

    // set image offset
    [tabItems[0] setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -30, 0)];
    ...
```

For uitabbaritem image resolution, 50x50px for @2x, and 75x75px for @3x.

Comment: thanks a lot, i've been searching for hours and trying to figure out why it didn't worked for me because i was using sf symbols

Comment: Use `imageWithoutBaseline()` to make the `imageInsets` work with SF symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
//On tabbar viewDidload
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    
    tabBar.items![0].imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: how can i achieve this using swiftui? inside onAppear/init() i tried to do something like this

UITabBar.appearance().items?[0].imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)

but that doesnt seem to work, any pointers?