# Maximize Size of UITabBarItem image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I would like to create a custom `UITabBarItem` with a Icon-image thats size is a little bit bigger than usual. The thing is I don't want to use a full replace of the background image because i would like to have the translucent effect of the TabBar.

So i would like to know 2 things:

1. What sizes are now correct for the new iOS7 `UITabBarItems` and their icons
2. How do I modify the size of the icon to display a bigger icon, because i dont want to show a title. Without the title its kinda small. In mind to keep the translucent effect displaying.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the icon’s visual style, create a toolbar or navigation bar icon in the following sizes:

About 44 x 44 pixels
About 22 x 22 pixels (standard resolution)
Regardless of the icon’s visual style, create a tab bar icon in the following sizes:

About 50 x 50 pixels (96 x 64 pixels maximum)
About 25 x 25 pixels (48 x 32 pixels maximum) for standard resolution

Have a look at these [Developers guide for bar & buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html)
[Bar icons in Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html)

Comment: just a question: what are these maximum sizes? Are those the whole button size?

Comment: Yes... whole button size

Comment: ah thx, here a answer that helped my 2. question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

To increase the size, try below code,

```
NSArray *items = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items;

for (UITabBarItem *b in items)
        b.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, -5, -5, -5);
```

If you want to decrease, try passing positive values to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top,left,bottom,right)`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**,

```
let array = tabBarController?.tabBar.items
for controller in array! {
    controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: -5, bottom: -5, right: -5)
}
```