# Make Selected UITabBarController Item Icon Larger

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement something like this:

[image: Tab bar sample]

What I want is the selected tab bar Item to show no title and make the icon larger.

Thing is, trying to change the item image frame is not working.

Any pointers?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving UITabBarItem Image down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the UITabBarItem's title to `nil` and set the `imageInsets`, something like this:

```
myTabBarItem.title = nil;
myTabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -10, 0);
```

Setting the title to `nil` keeps the title from displaying, then the image inset adjustment takes the space back that was reserved for the title.

Also see:
[Moving UITabBarItem Image down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down)