# UITabBar.ItemPositioning swift4

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbaritem

I am trying to set the positioning of my items in my `tabBar`, I want to lower the items towards the item title. Can I use `UITabBar.ItemPositioning` and if so how? Thank you.

How it looks now:

[image]

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

       myTabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: 100)

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down

Comment: Thank you, it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one, It should be helpful to you**

[image]