# How to decrease vertical padding between UITabBarItem image and text?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbaritem

I would like to decrease the vertical padding between the UITabBarItem and its text:

[image]

ie in order to make it look like this:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
    let pStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    pStyle.lineSpacing = -10.0
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.paragraphStyle: pStyle], for: .normal)
```

but it didn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving UITabBarItem Image down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adjust the position of the tab bar item title with an offset.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)
```

Comment: @Callarm i'm gonna have to respectfully ask you to change your name from _Callam_ to _Magician_ 

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer works for until iOS 15. For iOS 15 and later we have to set the title position adjustment using `UITabBarAppearance`:

```
let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)
tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```