# How to adjust the position of tab bar item iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I want to create a custom tabBar like this
[image]

Now I just can create a tabBar as below, I want the 4 tab bar Items (the add sign is a button)  to be centered and don't cover the button,  so the cart icon should move to the left a little bit, and the mall icon should move to the right. But I don't know how to adjust the position of tab bar item, neither using storyBoard or in a programmatic way.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should try adjusting the insets for the individual icons.  You can do this in the storyboard.

Check this post:
[Moving UITabBarItem Image down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285205/moving-uitabbaritem-image-down)

Answer (score 1):

Please modify `Item Position` in `Attributes Inspector` in Storyboard.

1. Select `Item position` as "`Centered`".
2. Choose `Custom` for `Width` and `Spacing`.
3. Play with the numbers for Width and Spacing and set it was you wish.

[image]

Comment: doesn't make any difference for me